# Reverse function of $x^3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So there is a problem I have came across, when researching for the reverse function of $$ f(x) = x^3 $$

The school book defines that: $$
 f^{-1}(x) =
  \begin{cases}
    \sqrt[3]{x}      & \quad \forall \text{x}  \geq0\\
    -\sqrt[3]{-x}  & \quad \forall \text{x}  <0\\
  \end{cases}
$$

However, every site on the web, including Symbolab, states that: $$f^{-1}(x)= \sqrt[3]x\quad \forall x\in R$$

Which is the correct answear?

Comment: Observe that $\sqrt[3]{-x} = -\sqrt[3]{x}$. BTW, _'reverse'_  is a very unusual terminology. _'Inverse'_ is what most texts use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every number has 3 cube roots. One real real root and two complex roots. These are all the cube roots of $-1$:

[image: Cube roots of -1]

In the context of real numbers, it is common for $\sqrt[3]x$ to denote the real cube root of $x$. But in the context of the complex numbers, $\sqrt[3]x$ denotes the principal cube root of $x$. The principal root is the complex root with the smallest angle (measured from the positive real axis). So for $-1$, the principal root is

$$ \sqrt[3]{-1} = \frac12 + \frac{\sqrt3}2 i.$$

This is what WolframAlpha gives you when you ask it for "$(-1)^{1/3}$". If you ask it for "cube root of $-1$" then it gives you an option between real and principal roots.

For positive real numbers, the real root and the principal root are the same. But for negative numbers, they are different.

Answer (score 1):

The book is taking no risk to deal with the root of a negative number (maybe it didn't discuss this yet). But the two solutions are equivalent.

Comment: Stupid downvote.

Answer (score 0):

The answers are equivalent: note that
$$-\sqrt[3]{-x} = -(\sqrt[3]{-1}\cdot\sqrt[3]{x}) = -(-\sqrt[3]{x}) = \sqrt[3]{x}$$
for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, by multiplicativity of the cube root. The question is a bit misleading, though, because $g(x) = \sqrt[3]{x}$ is *defined* as the inverse of $f(x) = x^3$ (at least in $\mathbb{R}$, there is no unique root in $\mathbb{C}$).